# AngularJS call to Google OAuth2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0

When I make this call, it opens the account selector, I can then select one of my google accounts, when I do, I get the error

```
Error: invalid_request

Missing required parameter: scope
```

I can see the scope variable in the URL in the account selector, but when I select the account, it loses the scope variable in the URL. I have changes my client ID in this example.
Thanks in Advance.

```
 app.controller("FirstController", function($scope, $location) {
$scope.redirectToGoogle = function () {
    console.log("redirectToGoogle");
    var client_id="myclientID";
    var scope="profile email";
    var redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback/";
    var response_type="token";
    var url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?&client_id="+client_id+"scope="+scope+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&response_type="+response_type;
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```

});

Comment: I changed this to $location.url(url) and $location.path(url),

Comment: I changed this to $location.url(url) and $location.path(url)   
$$path: "/https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?&client_id=clientID&scope=profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback/&response_type=token"
$$url: "/https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth%3F&client_id=clientid&scope=profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback/&response_type=token"

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it with the AngularJS $location service is:

```
var location = $location.url(url);
```

For more information see the [AngularJS $location service API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: I tried this, also with $location.path and I am getting the object back in the variable location, but now nothing displays.